# How to show git log view in IntelliJ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, intellij-idea

I'm using git in IntelliJ 10.5. My Changes Tool Windows shows me the local changes, but there is no log view tab. How can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug.

See

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-73403